# Multiple callouts for MapBox

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I need to display mutliple callouts for a set of annotations in MapView (actually just need show more information on top of annotations, thought that callouts is the way to go).

Is is possible? How can it be done?
Thanks

Comment: Hey  - can you post more specifically what you mean by multiple callouts? I think the mapbox function that allows you to create custom views for callouts only lets you return a single custom UIView.

Comment: When you select an annotation, it show a callout for that annotation. And if you select another, the former disappear and the new one is displayed. I need to show the "callouts view" of a set of annotations at the same time

Comment: Implement it custom then. However you're managing your data, you will need to call a custom function on your annotation view and just build custom callout views inside of each of your custom MGLAnnotationView subclass. I don't think there is a way to ask the callout views for a given set of annotation views as of the current SDK version.

Comment: Custom views are good to customize presentation of the callout view, but doesn't allow to present the callouts of a set of annotations at the same time